# Dispatching with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, dispatch

I'm trying to call a function from React JSX button and I have a problem with that because when in react-redux actions in the defined function I don't put dispatch function, works as it supposed to.

```
const like_function = (id) => {
      let post_id = id;

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    console.log(post_id, user_id);
    like_post(post_id, user_id);
  } else {
    <Redirect to="/login" />;
    console.log("Redirect to login");
  }
};
```

Here in this button I invoke function with one parameter.

```
<button onClick={() => like_function(post.id)}>Like</button>
```

This is redux action. Here is the problem. When dispatch is deleted function works but with dispatch is not even called, it wont even log data to console before async request

```
export const like_post = (post_id, user_id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const data = { post_id: post_id, user_id: user_id };
  console.log(data);
  dispatch({
    type: POST_LIKE_LOADING,
  });

  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/like_list/`, data);
    //console.log(res.data);
    dispatch({
      type: POST_LIKED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch({
      type: POST_LIKEING_FAIL,
    });
  }
};
```

Here are my redux reducers

```
case POST_LIKE_LOADING:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
  };
case POST_LIKED:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
    message: "OK"
  };
```

Sorry about my English, hope you understood me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're not dispatching the action.

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const dispatch = useDispatch()

dispatch(like_post(post_id, user_id))
```